# XML Count of child node

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

The xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tutorial xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<!--  ************************************** DAY 1 MODULE 1 **************************** -->

<qn day="1" module="1" id="1"  qntxt="Day 1 Mod 1 First qn?" ans="Answer 3" desc="The Correct answer is Answer3 because...">
        <opt id="Answer 1"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 2"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 3"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 4"></opt>
</qn>
<qn day="1" module="1" id="2" qntxt="Day 1 Mod 1 Second qn?" ans="Answer 22" desc="The Correct answer is Answer1 because...">
        <opt id="Answer 21"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 22"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 23"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 24"></opt>
</qn>
<qn day="1" module="1" id="3" qntxt="Day 1 Mod 1 Third qn?" ans="Answer 34" desc="The Correct answer is Answer4 because...">
        <opt id="Answer 31"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 32"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 33"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 34"></opt>
</qn>
```

I am parsing and inserting the the DayID, ModuleID to the db. This working fine.
Along with this I have insert the 'Total Number of Questions' - that is the count of 'opt' child node under each qn node. How can I get this?

```
function xmlParser(data) {

            dropTable();
            createTable();

            xml = data;
            var dayID, moduleID;
                $(xml).find('day').each(function()
                {
                    **alert($(this).children.length);**
                     dayID = $(this).attr('id');
                    $(this).find("module").each(function()
                    {



                         moduleID = $(this).attr('id');


                             DayID = dayID;  
                             ModuleID = moduleID;  
                             //CurScore = 0;
                             //HighScore = 0;

                            //alert(dayID +'--' + moduleID);
                            insertRecord(dayID,moduleID,0,0,0);
                    });

                });
        }
```

**I use - $(this).children.length; - but it gives me wrong value - i get 2 - Actual value would be 4.**

How can I get this, without further looping / much altering the code?

Comment: You can try $(this).find("opt").length to get the length of the child elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a specific tag, in our case `opt` you should pass that as a selection to `.children()`, since children otherwise takes all children of the tag. In your case however you are taking the length of a function object (`children` is a function object, `children('opt')` or `children()` is an invocation of said function)

```
$(xmlDoc).find("qn").each(function(){
    numberOfQuestions = $(this).children("opt").length;
});
```

note that in your specific case using `.find()` will give you the exact same number. However there's a difference between the two. `find` will travers the DOM from the selection to the bottom of the tree. That is if your XML changed to something like

```
<qn day="1" module="1" id="1"  qntxt="Day 1 Mod 1 First qn?" ans="Answer 3" desc="The Correct answer is Answer3 because...">
        <opt id="Answer 1">
             <qn day="1" module="1" id="1"  qntxt="Day 1 Mod 1 First qn?" ans="Answer 3" desc="The Correct answer is Answer3 because...">
                   <opt id="Answer 1"></opt>
                   <opt id="Answer 2"></opt>
                   <opt id="Answer 3"></opt>
                   <opt id="Answer 4"></opt>
            </qn>
        </opt>
        <opt id="Answer 2"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 3"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 4"></opt>
</qn>
```

then using `find('opt')` you would select 8 elements where as using `children('opt')` you'd get only 4. See this for further explanation of [`.children(\[selector\])`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/sPRgR/

HTML:-

```
<div id="test">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tutorial xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<!--  ************************************** DAY 1 MODULE 1 **************************** -->

<qn day="1" module="1" id="1"  qntxt="Day 1 Mod 1 First qn?" ans="Answer 3" desc="The Correct answer is Answer3 because...">
        <opt id="Answer 1"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 2"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 3"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 4"></opt>
</qn>
<qn day="1" module="1" id="2" qntxt="Day 1 Mod 1 Second qn?" ans="Answer 22" desc="The Correct answer is Answer1 because...">
        <opt id="Answer 21"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 22"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 23"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 24"></opt>
</qn>
<qn day="1" module="1" id="3" qntxt="Day 1 Mod 1 Third qn?" ans="Answer 34" desc="The Correct answer is Answer4 because...">
        <opt id="Answer 31"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 32"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 33"></opt>
        <opt id="Answer 34"></opt>
</qn>
    </div>
```

JS:-

```
$(function(){
    var xml = $("#test").html();
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
    $(xmlDoc).find("qn").each(function(){
        alert($(this).find("opt").length);
    });    
});
```